# Creating with Maven two separate jars, without dependencies and with ONLY dependencies

Tags: java, maven

Can Maven create two jars specified in one pom.xml: one jar with my app but without dependencies, and second jar ONLY with dependencies? I'd like to have two separate jars, but I want to run jar with my app and this app has to 'see' all dependencies in second jar. Everything I want to have in one eclipse project, only in result of one run of mvn:package I'd like to create separate jars...Is it possible? Now I use maven-jar-plugin to create jar with app, where I specify the classpath by add line in configuration of maven-jar-plugin:

```
<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
```

Before I have used maven-assebly-plugin to create jar-with-dependencies, but now I have to create separate jar-s....

Thanks in advance, seishin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

- use [`dependency:unpack`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html) to
  unpack all dependencies to a common
  folder,
- use the assembly plugin to [create a
  new JAR](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html) from the unpacked dependencies
- [provide a custom manifest](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifestFile.html) to your project's jar that
  links to the dependency jar